# Interrupt service routing in the ARM architecture

Tags: arm, isr

In the arm architecture which registers to update the address of ISR to the programme counter.
Does in GIC or vendor IC(like Ti, NxP) there is any hardware logic that provides ISR instruction address to the program counter?

Answer (score 1):

ARM CPUs use a so called *vector table*. It's an area in memory that contains the start addresses of all exception handlers aka ISRs.

So if the vector table starts at 0x08000000 and the *Systick* exception occurs, the CPU interrupts the current work and loads the *Systick* ISR start address into the program counter (PC). It can be found at 0x08000000 + 4 * 15 (as *Systick* has exception number 15).

Before PC is loaded, several registers (incl. PC) are saved on the stack.

The address of the vector table is configured via the VTOR register.

Exceptions 0 to 15 are given by the ARM architecture and are the same for all CPUs and MCUs. Exceptions numbers 16 and higher are vendor dependent and usually used for hardware related events such as UART, SPI, DMA events.